# Replacing wrong values (proved by 2 conditions) in a DataFrame with median values. ERROR of ambiguity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I know many people have asked this question, many answers are available. But this question a LITTLE different as in this problem we have two condition fulfilling to replace value with median value.

Before I explain in detail, I have taken this data-set from kaggle

https://www.kaggle.com/c/pubg-finish-placement-prediction/team

So,

This data-set have two features, 'damageDealt' and 'kills'. The convention is that when we deal damage to enemy he dies and without any damage, you can not kill.

Surprisingly, The PUBG API captured some glitched data, which made player kill without dealing any damage to the enemy.

```
a = data[data['damageDealt'] == 0.0]
b=a[a['kills'] > 0]
b['kills']
```

Here, we have 4153 rows. And

```
b['kills'].unique()
```

This returns array [1,2,3]

I want to replace all the 0.0 value in 'damageDealt' with median value of that 'damageDealt' where kills are 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

Moreover, I am not getting how to do this. Though, I have written a code with is giving me error.

```
median = data[data['kills'] == 1]['damageDealt'].median() # Finding median of 1 kills with some 
# damageDealt
np.where(data['damageDealt'] == 0.0 and data['kills'] == 1 , median ) # replaceing value where kills 
# is 1 but damageDealt is 0.0
```

This is the error I am getting.

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have also written different code but getting this or any other error.

Comment: _I want to replace all the 0.0 value in 'damageDealt' with median value of that 'damageDealt' where kills are 1, 2 and 3 respectively._ Do you want median excluding rows with damageDealt=0? Could you please elaborate more on what column you want to replace with exactly what?Is it the damageDealt you want to replace or kills?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
data.loc[(data['damageDealt'] == 0.0)&(data['kills'] == 1),'damageDealt']=median
```

Comment: thanks, actually yes. Previously I did not put round brackets here (data['damageDealt'] == 0.0), So, I was getting error.